# Finding full directory path

Tags: c#, .net, filepath

My C# application downloads a .zip that contains at least a .dcm file.

After decompression I get something like:

**download**/XXXX/YYYYYY/ZZZZZZ/**file.dcm**

I don't know the name of these intermediary X,Y,Z folders, and I don't know how many of them exist, but I'm certain that at least a single .dcm file exists at the end of the path.

How can I get the full path of folders between download and the folder with .dcm files? (assume Windows filesystem and .Net Framework 4.0).

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you are asking.  Assume you need a single function to accomplish your task.. tell us what the input(s) to that function are and the expected return value (output).

Comment: i think you know the path of the `downloads` and `filename`now you want to find the path between both right?

Comment: @Sudhakar: yes, exactly

Comment: This [Microsoft site](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303974) talks specifically about searching directories for a list of files that match a search pattern.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you a list of all the files contained within the download file that would match your filename:

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\path_to_download_folder", "file.dcm", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

You could then parse the returned filepaths for whatever parts you needed.  The [System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods will probably give you want you need instead of rolling your own.

Additionally, if your application might be downloading multiple files throughout the day, and you always need to retrieve the path of the very latest matching file, you could send the filepath to a [System.IO.FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx), which lets you get the creation time of the file, which you could use to determine which file is the newest.

Comment: Change "file.dcm" to "*.dcm" to just search for that extension

Comment: @jmstoker: `NO` i think OP wants to find the path of specific file,so `*.dcm` does not serve his purpose IMO

Comment: @Sudhakar: nope, I care about the extension, not the file name.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Either way that would make his code more flexible in case there are more.

Comment: @omgzor: Okay so you want to get all files inside that directory right

Comment: @omgzor: i think you need to know the `root` folder inside the `downloads` folder otherwise you endup in searching all folders inside the `downloads` folder